# Can't access/share Homegroup folders

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, homegroup

I have 1 system where everyone is able to access read/write to the homegroup folders. However, every other system can not access each others and the one system that all the other systems can read/write to, that one can not even access anyone's.

- There are no firewalls in place.
- They all are connected to the same hoemgroup
- The settings are as lose as possible
- The folders/computers can be seen just not accessed.
- Network Discovery is on.
- All systems are Windows 7
- Both Home, Work and Public all have everything on and enabled. Current group is home.

This is what I see when I try and access the HomeGroup for a laptop
http://prntscr.com/1k7k3y
The laptop can see and access this computer just fine. Double clicking on the icon do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure network discovery is on?

Enable or disable network discovery
Applies to Windows Vista
If your computer is connected to a network, network policy settings might prevent you from completing these steps.

By default, Windows Firewall blocks network discovery (formerly called UPnP technology), but you can enable it.

Open Network and Sharing Center by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Network and Internet, and then clicking Network and Sharing Center.

If network discovery is off, click the arrow button Picture of the arrow button‌ to expand the section.
Click Turn on network discovery, and then click Apply.  Administrator permission required If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/enable-or-disable-network-discovery

Answer (score 0):

Is file and printer sharing turned on? I have a similar situation but mine is intentional.

In the Network and Sharing Center, Click on "Change advanced sharing settings". There you will have three options:

- Home or Work
- Public
- Domain

The type of network connection you have set this up as will determine the group that you need to go into, or simply change the settings in all three.

Ensure that Network Discovery, File and Printer Sharing, and Public folder Sharing are turned on.

This should allow the clients to see each other and to access public files or folders. Keep in mind that if the files or folders are not set to public then they will not be seen.

Comment: Yes, it is set to Home and everything is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues sharing a folder even though everything looks like it is setup correctly:

1. Right-click on the folder to share and go to Properties.
2. Click on the Sharing tab, go down to Network path and click Share.
3. Click on the drop tab and add Everyone to the group.
4. Set your privileges and you are good to go.